# check for values before inflating

Tags: android

I have two `fragments` we will call them A & B. A is a `ListFrag` and B is a form for user input. The crude illustration below shows user interaction.

```
Fragment A    
<ListView>
Item1
Item2 <--link to fragment B
Item3
```

User clicks Item2 and sees

```
Fragment B
<TextView> - <EditText>
<TextView> - <EditText>
<TextView> - <EditText>
<save button>
```

User fills out the form, clicks save, and `Fragment` B passes the info back to `Fragment` A. `Fragment` A now makes a layout that was previously invisible set to a now visible state. `Fragment` A is also re inserted into the container so the user now see's.

```
Fragment A     
<TextView>   
<TextView>
<TextView>

<ListView>
Item1
Item2 <--link to fragment B
Item3
```

here is the code for onCreate

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_assets, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.assets_store_info);
        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String mStore = getArguments().getString("store");
        String mPhone = getArguments().getString("phone");
        String mAddress = getArguments().getString("address");
        String mCity = getArguments().getString("city");
        String mZip = getArguments().getString("zip");
        String mState = getArguments().getString("state");

        TextView store = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.store);
        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city);

        store.setText("Store #: " + mStore);
        phone.setText("Phone #: " + mPhone);
        address.setText(mAddress);
        city.setText(mCity + ", " + mZip + ", " + mState);
    }       
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

My problem is I need to insert a conditional statement like `if-else` into my `onCreate`. If I don't `Fragment` A will try and inflate variables with null values because they haven't been passed from `Fragment` B yet causing a crash. How should I go about doing this? I know I will need a `if (!=null)` I'm just not sure what to compare it against.

**Edit**

problem was solved by making the layout visible again in Fragment A rather than Fragment B. the code above is now working

Comment: Can't you handle the values inside fragment a? Separate the concerns, fragment a can look after its own ui elements and handle any null values passed in.

Comment: @Graham Smith not sure I follow you. I get that if Fragment A could handle its own UI it would eliminate the concerns but it has to get its values from Fragment B for this particular element. So how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B passes values through A.setArguments(), then this should work:

```
if (getArguments() != null)
```

Comment: This worked, but after some editing. I will post the code to show how I made it work